# UDK ParticleSystem Problem

Tags: udk, particles

I use below code to create my particles ( in fact, I don't know any other way.)

```
spawnedParticleComponents = WorldInfo.MyEmitterPool.SpawnEmitter(ParticleSystem'ParticleName', Location, Rotator );
spawnedParticleComponents.setTranslation(newLocation);
...
```

And unfortunately, I spawn many particles in game.

When I play my game, after some time, I see `Exceeded max active pooled emitters!` Warning in console .

To solve the problem, first, I tried `spawnedParticleComponents.DeactivateSystem();`, But it doesn't help.
Then I try `WorldInfo.MyEmitterPool.ClearPoolComponents(false);`, But it doesn't either .
:(

How can I destroy many spawned particles and avoid this warning ?

Comment: I found a problem. I noticed `DeactivateSystem()' doesn't deactive my particleSystemComponent !

Answer (score 1):

I solve it!

Just do as below when you don't need a ParticleSystemComponent anymore .

```
spawnedParticleComponents.SecondsBeforeInactive=0;
spawnedParticleComponents.DeactivateSystem();
spawnedParticleComponents.KillParticlesForced();
```